# How to convert html with vue component to pure html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know `new Vue({el: "#app"})` can render whole #app html, how to `new Vue(el: "html with vue component")`

here is my code:

```
<div id="app">  
</div>
<script>
  Vue.component("c", {template: `<div>is c</div>`})
  new Vue({el: "#app"})
  // after init app
  $("#app").append(parseVueComponent(`<c></c>`))
  // I expect result is
//   <div id="app">
// <div>is c</div>
// </div>
  // how to implement parseVueComponent
</script>
```

Comment: You can use components and import them globally/locally. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple: When you do `Vue.component()`, the first argument is the name of the reusable component. You can then use that name as an HTML tag! So if we have `Vue.component('my-component', { . . . })`, then all we have to do is:

```
<div id="app">
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, when I add vue component tag in js, I use `new Vue(el: "#app")` again, it will convert all current exist vue component tag, following is my code:

```
<script>
  Vue.component("c", {template: `<div>is c</div>`})
  new Vue({el: "#app"})

  $("#app").append(`<c></c>`)
  new Vue({el: "#app"})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you parsing the whole component? its the Vue's job to do. if all you want is render the text with accompanied html then you can use `v-html` directive which parses and display the html and text for you. here is a small snippet to give you the idea:

```
data() {
   return {
     textWithHTML : '<div id="unique">my text</div>'
 }
}
```

now to use/render/parse this we will use v-html like so in `template`

```
<template>
   <div v-html="textWithHTML"></div>
</template>
```